# AWS Lambda create function with trigger

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I can create lambda function from AWS SDK something like that:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda();
lambda.createFunction({
    FunctionName: 'name',
    Code: {
      ZipFile: 'zip content'
    },
    Role: 'role'
  }).promise();
```

But how can i specify that this function should trigger with S3 upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this from the S3 SDK, specifically [putBucketNotificationConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketNotificationConfiguration-property).

You configure a notification configuration that indicates a Lambda function as the handler for specific S3 notification events, for example s3:ObjectCreated:Put. Be aware that, depending on how the upload happens, uploads can result in different events, e.g. Put, Post, and  CompleteMultipartUpload.